# Msbuild get OutputPath from main project

Tags: msbuild

Say I have a `game.exe` that depends on `engine.dll`. When I build the `game.csproj` I want the `engine.csproj` to copy some stuff to the OutputPath of the project that is referencing it. 
So in this example case, I want `engine.csproj` to copy something to the **OutputPath** of `game.csproj`

How do I get the $(OutputPath) of `game.csproj` in `engine.csproj`?

The reason I want to do this is because I'm building a content project in game and engine like this:

```
<Target Name="BuildContent">
    <MSBuild Projects="Content\Content.contentproj" 
             Properties="OutputPath=MAINPROJECTPATH" />
</Target>
```

So I need to specify the **OutputPath** to the 'main project' which is the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit nosing around in some of the msbuild targets I found the solution.

I should pass through the Parent properties like this

```
<Target Name="BuildContent">
      <MSBuild Projects="Content\Content.contentproj" 
               Properties="ParentOutputDir=$(ParentOutputDir); 
                           ParentIntermediateDir=$(ParentIntermediateDir); 
                           ParentProjectDir=$(ProjectDir);" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is not clear from the question exactly what extra files you need to be copied that will not happen automatically using inter-project references.

If the Game project includes a **project** reference (rather then just a DLL file reference) to the Engine project, msbuild should copy all the output from Engine into the Game output directory, doesn't it?

If you really do need to manually copy files between projects, then I do not believe there is any easy way to find out which projects reference the current project, so it would probably be simpler to create a level of indirection with Engine pushing files half way and Game (or any other projects that need to include those files) pulling the files the rest of the way:

1. Some **post**-build event code in Engine.csproj created a "*References*" directory under SolutionDir and copies the files it wants to share into there.
2. Then Game.csproj can include the files from the "*References*" directory - either as direct file references, or by copying with some **pre**-build event code in Game.csproj

Comment: The reason I need this is because I'm building a project inside an other project like this (in the csproj file): <MSBuild Projects="Content\Content.contentproj" Properties="OutputPath=MAINPROJECTPATH"></MSBuild>

Comment: Imagine you need to compile shaders that are inside of Engine project. Now, these result files you need to copy to Game output folder. How to do it?